# Increasing request timeout of 110s

Tags: web-config, azure-web-app-service, iis-8, azure-app-service-plans

I cannot seem to extend the 110 second timeout for requests to my Azure Web App. I have done the following in order to increase this limit, but with no success.

ASP.NET's HTTP request execution timeout (web.config):

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime executionTimeout="600" />
</system.web>
```

IIS connection timeout (web.config):

```
<system.applicationHost>
  <webLimits connectionTimeout="00:10:00" />
</system.applicationHost>
```

Kudu timeout before external commands are killed (site app setting):

```
SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT = 600
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> request timeout of 110s

It is very odd that your request timeout of 110s,From the [Auzre official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-availability-performance-application-issues-faq#why-does-my-request-time-out-after-240-seconds), we could know that default timeout is about 4 minutes.It seems that we are not able to increase request timeout. The following is the snippet from the document. Please have a try to scale up and scale down back the [App service plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/azure-web-sites-web-hosting-plans-in-depth-overview#scale-an-app-service-plan). If still have the same issue, please connect to Azure support team for more help.

> Azure Load Balancer has a default idle timeout setting of four minutes. This is generally a reasonable response time limit for a web request. If your web app requires background processing, we recommend using Azure WebJobs. The Azure web app can call WebJobs and be notified when background processing is finished. You can choose from multiple methods for using WebJobs, including queues and triggers.
>   + 
>   WebJobs is designed for background processing. You can do as much background processing as you want in a WebJob. For more information about WebJobs, see [Run background tasks with WebJobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-create-web-jobs).

**Note** :`SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT = 600` could use for your build process launches some command in the server side. But the request is timeout that will cause clients to get disconnected after 230 seconds, we could get more info from [Azure Kudu Configurable settings](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Configurable-settings).